# How to choose the correct toilet flapper (on the web)?

Tags: toilet

Are flappers color coded?  If not, how do I go about buying a flapper on the web?  They all look sort of the same.  How likely is it that a flapper that looks right on the web will fit my toilet?

Thanks.

Comment: Many are interchangeable, however there are two major sizes, 2" openings used to be the standard however the newer models with smaller gallon per flush ratings will have a 3" opening (the larger opening increases flush velocity which is important when there is less water in the tank to flush with).

Comment: If you know the make and model of your toilet, use that in the google query. Notice that some generic flappers have a ring that is to be shifted to set the number of "exposure holes" for your toilet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure take your old flapper with you to an actual store to buy the replacement. Buying online is great if you know exactly what you need but the guess work when you are unsure is a crap shoot.

Colors of flappers are almost always a signal of the manufacturer and in some cases specific to a particular style of flapper from that manufacturer.